# Turn Off Calendar Alerts for Certain Calendars

Tags: calendar, gmail, notifications

I have several calendars that I need to view an access, but I don't necessarily want the alerts coming in for all of them.

[image]

Is there a way to turn off all other notifications except my account (in green above)?  What about per calendar?

They are all Gmail accounts if that helps.

I have already tried this setting but it didn't make a difference.

[image]

I have also looked at the notification settings on each calendar in Gmail, which are showing `No reminders set`

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Calendar on your Mac.
2. In the left column list of calendars, right click (or command-I) on the calendar in question and "Get Info"
3. Check the box labeled "Ignore alerts"
4. Hit "OK"